# Area of an irregular polygon

Tags: python, python-3.x, computational-geometry

```
"""
Provides a way to caculate the area of an arbitrary
n-sided irregular polygon.
"""
import doctest
import math

def heron(a,b,c):
    """
    Uses the heron formula to calculate the area
    of the triangle where `a`,`b` and `c` are the side
    lengths.

    >>> heron(3, 4, 5)
    6.0
    >>> heron(7, 10, 5).__round__(2)
    16.25
    """
    s = (a + b + c) / 2
    return math.sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c))

def pytagoras(a, b):
    """
    Given the cathets finds the hypotenusas.

    >>> pytagoras(3, 4)
    5.0
    """
    return math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)

def distance(point_1, point_2):
    """
    Computes the cartesian distance between two points.

    >>> distance((0,0), (5,0))
    5.0
    """
    delta_x = point_1[0] - point_2[0]
    delta_y = point_1[1] - point_2[1]
    return pytagoras(delta_x, delta_y)

def triangle_area(triangle):
    """
    Wraps `heron` by allowing points inputs instead
    of sides lengths inputs.

    >>> triangle_area([(0,0), (0,3), (4,0)])
    6.0
    """
    side_1 = distance(triangle[0], triangle[1])
    side_2 = distance(triangle[1], triangle[2])
    side_3 = distance(triangle[2], triangle[0])
    return heron(side_1, side_2, side_3)

def triplets(list_):
    """
    Yields items from a list in groups of 3.

    >>> list(triplets(range(6)))
    [(0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]
    """
    for index, item in enumerate(list_[:-2]):
        yield item, list_[index + 1], list_[index + 2]

def polygon_area(polygon):
    """
    Calculates the area of an n-sided polygon by
    decomposing it into triangles. Input must be
    a list of points.

    >>> polygon_area([(0,0), (0,5), (3,0), (3, 5)])
    15.0
    """
    return sum(triangle_area(triangle)
                   for triangle in triplets(polygon))

def _main():
    doctest.testmod()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _main()
```

Comment: You accepted [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/86539/11728) but you don't seem to have taken notice of it — several of the comments there also apply here.

Comment: @GarethRees sorry I did not think that I was reusing similar functions over again without looking at the built-ins... I will think about wheter the standard library contains them next time

Comment: Also, point 5 from the earlier answer is still relevant here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ["shoelace" formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) finds the area of a simple polygon:

```
from __future__ import division

def polygon_area(points):  
    """Return the area of the polygon whose vertices are given by the
    sequence points.

    """
    area = 0
    q = points[-1]
    for p in points:  
        area += p[0] * q[1] - p[1] * q[0]
        q = p
    return area / 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    square = [(0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0)]
    irregular = [(1,1), (1,5), (2,5), (5,1)]
    print('Unit square area: {}'.format(polygon_area(square)))
    print('Irregular polygon area: {}'.format(polygon_area(irregular)))
```

This outputs:

```
Unit square area: 1.0
Irregular polygon area: 10.0
```

Answer (score 4):

The algorithm is wrong! Consider this polygon:

[image: Orange quadrilateral with vertices (1,1), (1,5), (2,5) and (5,1)]

It's easy to see that this an area of 10, but:

```
>>> polygon_area([(1,1), (1,5), (2,5), (5,1)])
3.9999999999999973
```

That's because the `polygon_area` algorithm adds the two red triangles shown in the figure below, each of which has area 2:

[image: Two red triangles with vertices (1,1), (1,5), (2,5) and (1,5), (2,5), (5,2) respectively superimposed on the orange quadrilateral.]